# sails app with io.socket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

i am using below code to get  notification in real time time but if the receiver is offline or not on that page they can't see the notification after login. can anyone please help me in this:

```
io.socket.on('chat',function(obj){      

      io.socket.get('/chat',function(obj){
        console.log(obj.userData)
        var count = Object.keys(obj.userData).length;
  console.log(count);


        //  $scope.chatList.push(obj.userData);
           $scope.chatList = obj.userData;
          $scope.$apply();


      });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

To start listening to new chat objects you should do first Get and than listen to events.

Like that:

```
  io.socket.get('/chat',function(body, response){    
      // start listening for chat objects
  });

   io.socket.on('chat',function(event){     
       console.log(event.data.userData)
       var count = Object.keys(event.data.userData).length;
       console.log(count);


        //  $scope.chatList.push(event.data.userData);
        $scope.chatList = event.data.userData;
        $scope.$apply();

   });
```